# Where does the word "puppet" come from?

Tags: etymology

Where does the word *puppet* come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=puppet) and [myEtymology](http://www.myetymology.com/english/puppet.html) mention:

> 1520s (implied in puppetry),

- from Old French poupette, dim. of poupée "doll" (13c.),

  - from Vulgar Latin root *puppa,

    - from Latin pupa "girl, doll" (see [pupil](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pupil)).

> **Metaphoric extension to "person whose actions are manipulated by another" first recorded 1540s**.

More details in this ["Word of the day" entry](http://podictionary.com/?p=230), including about the related word puppy:

> In the middle ages lap dogs were also called **`poupée`** because they were thought of as playthings—not working dogs.
>   `Poupée` morphed to puppy and so with time any little dog began to be called a puppy.

Note: the [origin of the word **puppeteer** is more recent](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/robert-loerzel/chicago-puppeteer-city_b_634493.html) (1915).